# CollabNet SVN won't dump a repository

Tags: svn, collabnet

For an unknown reason, *Collabnet SVN* will not dump some of my the repositories, although the others it dumps correctly. The problem is observed with both manual dumps via `Repositories->Dump` and automatic ones via `Repositories->Backup Schedule`. In both cases, the job appears under *Finished Background Jobs* with a zero execution time—the *Started at* and *Finished at* fields are the same.

Why can this happen? The affected repositories are not empty, contain revisions, and I am not specifying any specific range on the dump page, expecting *SVN* to dump it entire. A manual invocation of `svnadmin dump` works well, but I should like to use the backup scheduler available through the web-interface instead of writing my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mark Phippard* of the SVN forums [suggested](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=660421) that I check the console log, where I found the following:

```
WARN admin.RepoDumpJob - Backup skipped: A backup for
repo 'ProjectsNew' is already running, as indicated by
prior existence of progress log
'C:\csvn\data\log​s\temp\job-progres​s-ProjectsNew-dump.l​og'
```

Deleting that file solved the problem, but I still bear a grudge against *SvnEdge* for forcing the user to rummage in messy log files instead of reporting the error where the user gave the command—that is in the web interface.